# Hyphens missing from output

Tags: fonts, fontspec, babel

The main language of my book is Hindi, and English is the other language for some notes and information like ISBN. I realized that for some fonts like Charis-SIL, some hyphens in the input go missing in the output. Here is an example with a random ISBN number:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelprovide[main]{hindi}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Devanagari}
\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{CharisSIL}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
\noindent नमस्ते। ISBN-13: 978-8-9025-4027-5.\\
\foreignlanguage{english}{ISBN-13: 978-8-9025-4027-5.}\\
{\englishfont ISBN-13: 978-8-9025-4027-5.}\\
\end{document}
```

When compiled on Overleaf with LuaLaTeX (Tex Live version 2020), the output looks like this

[image]

In the second line, for Charis SIL, only one hyphen is seen. In the third line, all hyphens are seen as expected. If I change `englishfont` to `Charis SIL`, the error occurs in the third line also. Is this an issue with the font `Charis SIL` or an issue with the way I am defining/using the font in the LaTeX code?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your bug with the hyphens on the second line in TeX Live 2021. I do get the missing Latin Letters in Noto Serif Devanagari, which is a font issue. (Adding `onchar=fonts` to switch language whenever you start typing in Latin or Devanagari would fix that.)

Comment: One bug that might possibly be related: `\defaultfontfeatures{Script=Devanagari}` wull erroneously attempt to change the script of the English font, too. You should simply omit it; `\babelfont` adds the appropriate `Script=` and `Language=` tags for you.

Comment: You might also try adding `Renderer=HarfBuzz` for only the fonts that need it, e.g. `\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Noto Serif Devanagari}`.

Comment: You could also test whether this is an issue with the font missing characters by adding ``\tracinglostchars=3`. That is unlikely, since the first hyphen worked.